# Timed out receiving message from renderer: 9.999 ,while taking screenshot

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, appium

I am running the appium hybrid app.While taking screenshot i am getting "org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 9.999". Only while taking the screen shot i have the issues while in other cases its working fine.

I tried it changing the chrome driver version but got the same result

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        File destFile =new File(screenShotPath);
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile,destFile );
```

Comment: I found the solution by adding a capability in appium drive , the issue sloved capabilities.setCapability("nativeWebScreenshot", true);